# Create Git Log using Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, git-commit, git-log, git-webhooks

We need to generate commit history file automatically when user commits code into git repository.

It can be done using Jenkins, Gitlab Webhooks and Jenkins Git Changelog plugin. Also, it can be created using below git command.

```
$ git log --pretty=format:'At %ci, %cN committed %h : %s' --decorate --graph >log.log
```

But, is there anyway we can generate commit history file using Gitlab CI/CD operations. The file can be saved in git repositry or local storage.

**Sample Commit History File**

```
* At 2018-11-16 18:02:21, kRiZ committed 1714a95 : Commit 4
* At 2018-11-15 16:06:06, kRiZ committed bab5c0c : Commit 3
* At 2018-11-14 18:05:09, kRiZ committed b3c9d86 : Commit 2
* At 2018-11-14 06:47:34, kRiZ committed 8e6ee30 : Add README.md
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there are multiple ways of doing this in GitLab. Here's one:

1. Create a `.gitlab-ci.yaml` file at the root of your repository. You can do this locally or using GitLab's web UI.
2. Paste this snippet into your `.gitlab-ci.yaml` file:

   ```
   changelog:
     image: docker:git
     script:
       - git log --pretty=format:'At %ci, %cN committed %h - %s' --decorate --graph >log.log
     artifacts:
       paths: [log.log]
   ```
3. Either commit and push locally or commit on GitLab's Web UI. The `changelog` job will be triggered.
4. After the job has finished successfully, your `log.log` file will be available as an artifact of the `changelog` job

Essentially, with this snippet you are setting up GitLab's CI/CD system to:

- Use the [Docker executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html) with a Docker image with `git` preinstalled
- Define a `changelog` [job](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#jobs) that will run your git command
- Define a `log.log` [artifact](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pipelines/job_artifacts.html) that will be generated as part of the job and stored, so that you can download it afterwards.

I'd also recommend checking out the [GitLab CI/CD quickstart](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/quick_start/)

Comment: But, is there someway we update log file within gitlab repository? or some way other than saving log file in server or artifacts?

Answer (score 1):

The [library](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/git-changelog-lib) used by the [Jenkins plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-changelog-plugin) also has a [command line tool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-changelog-command-line) that can be used in anywhere:

```
npx git-changelog-command-line -std -tec "
# Changelog

Changelog for {{ownerName}} {{repoName}}.

{{#tags}}
## {{name}}
 {{#issues}}
  {{#hasIssue}}
   {{#hasLink}}
### {{name}} [{{issue}}]({{link}}) {{title}} {{#hasIssueType}} *{{issueType}}* {{/hasIssueType}} {{#hasLabels}} {{#labels}} *{{.}}* {{/labels}} {{/hasLabels}}
   {{/hasLink}}
   {{^hasLink}}
### {{name}} {{issue}} {{title}} {{#hasIssueType}} *{{issueType}}* {{/hasIssueType}} {{#hasLabels}} {{#labels}} *{{.}}* {{/labels}} {{/hasLabels}}
   {{/hasLink}}
  {{/hasIssue}}
  {{^hasIssue}}
### {{name}}
  {{/hasIssue}}

  {{#commits}}
**{{{messageTitle}}}**

{{#messageBodyItems}}
 * {{.}} 
{{/messageBodyItems}}

[{{hash}}](https://github.com/{{ownerName}}/{{repoName}}/commit/{{hash}}) {{authorName}} *{{commitTime}}*

  {{/commits}}

 {{/issues}}
{{/tags}}
"
```